# UnknownError from Graph API when accessing Sharepoint documents

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, sharepoint-online

I have a multitenant app where multiple tenants at random gets a non-helpfull error "UnknownError", when accessing the sharepoint documents through Graph API.
This happens when listing files in a folder, uploading files, either directly or chunked, or getting file content.
I will list some request id's and maybe someone from MS could have a look as to what the error means:

```
Url: /v1.0/groups/ed8a202b-b7bd-42bd-8a91-5642b9d17b01/drive/items/01JCQPBHZ7ZWY7KUXPHJBLUNC7CJ3QMNAD
Request ID: e4c8c765-d9bd-425f-855a-00362d3b18b5
Time: Fri, 22 Mar 2019 08:30:39 GMT

Url: /v1.0/groups/ed8a202b-b7bd-42bd-8a91-5642b9d17b01/drive/root:/xxxxx/xxxxxxx/xxxxxxxxx.pdf:/microsoft.graph.createUploadSession
Request ID: f588cec1-f3d5-4803-8d0e-251b6b611584
Time:Fri, 22 Mar 2019 07:08:45 GMT
```

Update:
Here are some response headers from a request:

```
[
  {
    "Transfer-Encoding": "chunked"
  },
  {
    "request-id": "edc0c4ba-24ac-46e2-aa7d-1c423e0995c0"
  },
  {
    "client-request-id": "edc0c4ba-24ac-46e2-aa7d-1c423e0995c0"
  },
  {
    "x-ms-ags-diagnostic": {
      "ServerInfo": {
        "DataCenter": "West Europe",
        "Slice": "SliceC",
        "Ring": "5",
        "ScaleUnit": "001",
        "RoleInstance": "AGSFE_IN_4",
        "ADSiteName": "WEU"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "Duration": "10048.6264"
  },
  {
    "Strict-Transport-Security": "max-age=31536000"
  },
  {
    "Cache-Control": "private"
  },
  {
    "Date": "Fri, 29 Mar 2019 15:24:21 GMT"
  }
]
```

UPDATE 08/05-2019:

I looks like all UnknownError errors across all our customers are originating from DataCenter: WestEurope, Slice: SliceC (according to headers). Different Rings and Instanses though (even for same customer)

Most of the time it's this request that is failing:

/v1.0/groups/{tenantid}/drive/root:/{folder}/{folder}/{folder}/{filename}:/microsoft.graph.createUploadSession

Comment: After adding som more logging this looks like some sort of timeout issue. It always happens after 10 seconds (within a few hundred ms). However it's now the OverallTimeout on the C# SDK HttpProvider as it's set for 100 seconds (and that results in a timeout error instead)

Comment: Right now is also seems to be same datacenter this is happening in: 
DataCenter: West Europe,
Slice: SliceC
Ring:5

Comment: It also seems that the sharepoint portal has issues. I get "StoreBusyRetryLater"

Comment: Please include the actual error payload in the result. The URL and Request ID isn't really enough to go on.

Comment: Can you use header? I'm not sure I can get the response from the c# sdk

Comment: I've updated the question with headers

Comment: It looks like there's an Error object in the ServiceException. I'll update the code to log it, and post here when I have data

Comment: That didn't help alot. This is a serialized Error object: {"code":"UnknownError","innererror":{"request-id":"211b6e33-86cf-4359-93f9-23edb5b343e1","date":"2019-04-01T02:08:22"},"message":""}

It looks like the error IS 'UnknownError'

How do we proceed?

Comment: You'll want to use a tool like Fiddler to see exactly what is going down the wire.

Comment: As the error is on the server side, it is quite hard for users to get the right answer. Opening a support ticket at microsoft should be the best option the get the root cause of the error. As your're programming against services in the cloud you should use some kind of resilience library (e.g. [Polly](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly) to cope with such errors. Furthermore i suggest to dig into [Cloud Architecture patterns](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/patterns/retry).

Comment: @PeterSchneider I'm using Polly various places already, but most errors I have from Graph API aren't transient - they plague a tenant for several hours, both this UnknowError but also "file is locked" on files that are not open by anyone. Opening a support ticket is not possible as I'm a developer using a free cloudservice - I was redirected to SO or Github, depending on the problem. I'm considering caching sharepoint file metadata on server, but as the Delta query is not working either, that's not an option yet

Comment: This error can happen when the SharePoint service takes longer than Microsoft Graph expects for tasks to complete.  The requested action can still be processing when Graph decides to send the error response.  Are you seeing cases where if you check to see whether it was actually done a few seconds later you see the results you expect?  This is likely a performance issue with the tenant and not really an API usage issue.  A support ticket with Office 365 is definitely the right next step.  You should be able to contact support from [https://portal.office.com]

Comment: Yes sometimes the file appears after 10-20 seconds. I’ll try to open a ticket, thanks

Comment: Could someone at MS please respond to this. I have one tenant (out of 150) that is failing 90 % of calls to Sharepoint for the last 48 hours (tenant id af43b8c0-b71d-43b8-8444-c8163f3780d2). I've opened a ticket in portal.office.com, and as expected I got rejected, because it's not releated to the portal. @MarcLaFleur - anyone?

Comment: Since I'm not in support I, unfortunately, cannot look up the ticket to see why they support bounced this but they're the only group I'm aware of that could address this (it isn't a Graph issue). You may want to try talking to someone directly rather than using the online form. O365 support can be reached @ (800) 865-9408

Comment: Hi @MarcLaFleur. Thanks for responding, however I do think that Graph is partly at fault. When doing specific operations against graph (createuploadsession for example), graph expects sharepoint to respond within 10 seconds (so my research shows anyway) or it returns UnknownError and the sharepoint api continues to process behind the scenes. When sharepoint is overloaded it doesn’t respond within 10 seconds. It would be NICE for graph to wait for sharepoint to timeout and return that error instead, to respond (and report errors) appropriately

Comment: @MarcLaFleur I spoke to support, but as Sharepoint doesn't fail in the portal (I suppose they use the old API), but it's only slow, they can't do much. 
What would it take to make the Graph API usable? Right now the Graph API is unreliable if the service it calls is slow. It's frustration to use the Graph API in a professional capacity, when I can't trust it. If I receive an error I expect it to relevant/informative and correct, meaning that if the call fails nothing has happened. Right now I can upload a file, get an UnknownError and minutes later find the file uploaded in Sharepoint anyway.

Comment: @MarcLaFleur Why doesn't Graph API not just wait for Sharepoint API to fail and report that error (maybe Graph like message)? Or succeed after mayby 30 or 40 seconds, if it's slow?